# Trigger to insert values from another table

Tags: plsql, triggers, insert

I am not able to find the answer using search. How can I get the value for column `FK_SOCRD_ID` from table `CR_MDT` to insert into table `CR_MDT_AUDIT` using this trigger I have created:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "CR_MDT_AUDIT" 
before insert or delete or update on CR_MDT
for each row 
declare 
  V_user varchar2 (30);
  V_date varchar2 (30); 
begin 
  IF inserting THEN
     insert into CR_MDT_AUDIT (new_value, OLD_VALUE, user_name, entry_date, operation, FK_SOCRD_ID)
     VALUES (:NEW.CR_MDT_ABSTRACTOR_DT, NULL, v_user, v_date, 'Abstraction Completed');
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
     insert into CR_MDT_AUDIT (new_value, OLD_VALUE, user_name, entry_date, operation, FK_SOCRD_ID)
     VALUES (null, :OLD.CR_MDT_ABSTRACTOR_DT, v_user, v_date, 'delete');
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
     insert into CR_MDT_AUDIT (new_value, OLD_VALUE, user_name, entry_date, operation, FK_SOCRD_ID)
     VALUES (:NEW.CR_MDT_ABSTRACTOR_DT, :OLD.CR_MDT_ABSTRACTOR_DT, v_user, v_date, 'Update');
  END IF;
END;
```

I don't know what clause or wording to use so that the `FK_SOCRD_ID` value from `CR_MDT` adds to `CR_MDT_AUDIT` table. Basically, I am trying to have a way to identify where the changes are being made.

Comment: Do you mean you want to know which column had been changed during the update? You can compare column values in `NEW` and `OLD` one by one.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, no I want the values that are on CR_MDT to pass to table CR_MDT_AUDIT. It will be a constant value that I want to pass to CR_MDT_AUDIT. It's a way I can use to identify where the changes were made.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. If `FK_SOCRD_ID` is a column in table `CR_MDT`, then you can access it with `:NEW.FK_SOCRD_ID` or `:OLD.FK_SOCRD_ID`.

Comment: Okay cool that worked. I should of tried that before posting. I thought I could only use :new and :old when there was an update, delete, or insert happening to a column. Thanks Dmitry!